# Elasticsearch: prefer prefix match over term match

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got a field in elasticsearch index, in which I'm trying to search and I'd like for the documents where this field's value begins with the search term to be higher up than documents, where the term is somewhere in the middle of a long phrase. E.g.:
When searching for "lorem",

```
{
  "title": "Lorem"
}
```

should have higher score than

```
{
  "title": "The time I said Lorem"
}
```

or

```
{
  "title": "The Lorem"
}
```

or even

```
{
  "title": "Lorem impsum"
}
```

However this is often not the case with a simple `match`, `match_phrase_prefix` or `query_string` query.

So far I've tried combining `prefix` query with a `match` query while boosting the prefix, but the boosting doesn't seem to work as I expected, i.e. the results are the same just boosted by 10

```
...
{
    "should": [
        {
            "prefix": {
                "title": {
                    "value": query,
                    "boost": 10
                }
            }
        }
        {
            "match": {
                "title": {
                    "query":     query,
                    "boost":     3,
                    "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
...
```

Also, not sure if this is relevant, but the `title` field is actually nested, i.e. it's `alternative_names.title`

Is there any elegant solution to this with elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination [`bool/should`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) clause to achieve your required results.

Adding a working example

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "alternative_names": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index data:**

```
{
  "alternative_names": {
    "title": "Lorem"
  }
}
{
  "alternative_names": {
    "title": "The time I said Lorem"
  }
}
{
  "alternative_names": {
    "title": "The Lorem"
  }
}
{
  "alternative_names": {
    "title": "Lorem impsum"
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "alternative_names",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "term": {
                "alternative_names.title.keyword": "Lorem"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "alternative_names.title": "Lorem"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "66500753",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1", 
        "_score": 1.3436072,
        "_source": {
          "alternative_names": {          // note this
            "title": "Lorem"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "66500753",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 0.11474907,
        "_source": {
          "alternative_names": {
            "title": "Lorem impsum"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "66500753",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.11474907,
        "_source": {
          "alternative_names": {
            "title": "The Lorem"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "66500753",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.07477197,
        "_source": {
          "alternative_names": {
            "title": "The time I said Lorem"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @sveatlo did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work for some use cases in my dataset. when searching for "hlava" the results are in this order: `["Mluvící hlava","Zebří hlava","Hlava Medúzy (8)","Hlava Medúzy (8)","Hlava Medúzy (8)","Hlava Medúzy (8)","Těžká je hlava...","Těžká je hlava...","Těžká je hlava...","Hlava v kontejneru"], which doesn't seem right`. I'd expect "Hlava meduzy (8)" to be first.

Comment: Could you try to explain me why doesn't my original attempt with boosting the prefix query work?

Comment: i found out the problem was in my dataset, where some titles where indexed several times thus lowering the term's weight. i solved it using a custom scripted similarity and it works like charm